# How can I ensure that my welb application is compatible with latest browser versions

Tags: web-applications, browser

I have a web applicaiton written in Perl,C++ and MYSQL how can I ensure that the application is compatible with the latest version of the Browsers that are available in the market.How can I ensure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the more reliable way is to test your application yourself with the latest version of the major browers.